# In .htaccess remove word from URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

After more than one hour of searching, I still can't figure out how to redirect a link from `http://site/fr/other` to `http://site/other`.

I am using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/fr/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the first forward slash: `RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]`.

Try this out at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

Comment: thanks, you were right, but now, if the user types site/fr it gives them a 404, but the site/fr/ works. Should I add a rule for the case site/fr ?

Comment: Yes, you can add another rule: `RewriteRule ^fr$ / [L,R=301,QSA]`.

Comment: thanks again, it worked ! The combined one looks much cleaner. Have a nice day

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I deleted the combined one (`RewriteRule ^fr((?:/.*$)?) $1 [L,R=301,QSA]`) because `http://site/france` would redirect to `http://site/ance`, which I don't think is expected behavior.

Comment: Alright, this combined rule may be better: `RewriteRule ^fr((?:(?:\s*|/.*)$)) $1 [L,R=301,QSA]`. `http://site/france` does not redirect to `http://site/ance`; `http://site/fr ` redirects to `http://site/`; `http://site/fr/` redirects to `http://site/`; `http://site/fr/other` redirects to `http://site/other`.

Answer (score 2):

To remove '-xyz-' from the url

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-xyz-(.*).html$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1-$2.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

To remove 'xyz' from the url 'http://yoursite.com/xyz/some-url.html'

```
RewriteRule ^xyz/(.*)\.html$ $1-watches.html [L,R=301]
```

To remove 'xyz' from the url 'http://yoursite.com/some-dir/xyz/some-url.html'

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/xyz/(.*).html$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2.html [NC,R=301,L]
```