# How to remove specific character from url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

We want to remove specific characters from the url using htaccess.

for example `http://www.example.com/#/music.php` which is redirect to `http://www.example.com/music.php` using `htaccess` rules.

we used the following code but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.html$ /#/music.php [L]
```

Comment: Part after `#` doesn't reach your webserver.

Comment: please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839047/in-htaccess-remove-word-from-url for your problem.