# How to remove last element from URL with PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have `$url = "example.com/en/category/node/extra/";` and I need to remove `extra` from `$url`, how could I do that?

Comment: explode, array_pop and implode again?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am missing the context here. You could rewrite the url without the extra. Else I would suggest a bit of htaccess here. In that case, its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839047/in-htaccess-remove-word-from-url

Comment: @Dorvalla no,no, htaccess is not an option in this case. I just need to remove the last segment of a url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explode the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] into an array, remove empty elements, and then remove the last array element.  Then, implode it all back together with initial and trailing slashes.

```
$urlArray = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']);
$urlArray = array_filter($urlArray); 

// remove last element
array_pop($urlArray);

$urlString = '/'.implode('/',$urlArray).'/';
```

Don't store `array_pop()` as a variable, unless you need the last array element.

Answer (score 2):

`$url = "example.com/en/category/node/extra/";
echo basename($url); 
echo dirname($url);`

returns

`extra
example.com/en/category/node`

Answer (score 1):

Many ways,

1. explode pop last, then implode.
2. Use regex replace the last part
3. **I prefer: append ../ to make it like "example.com/en/category/node/extra/../"** because this cost less computation, and its more efficient

If you are interested in one of it and do not know how to do that exactly, leave me a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `preg_replace` function.

```
preg_replace('~/[^/]*/([^/]*)$~', '//\1', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gG0uM0/2)

Comment: why this [^/]* it is not required. url will not contain any space remember. end it out to here /[^/]*/$

Answer (score 0):

try this as your regex

```
[^/]+/$ //to get last and replace it with empty
```