# Mod rewriting using .htaccess friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-modification

My url is `http://example.com/product/Braided/table-fan`

And i want to rewrite like this `http://example.com/Braided/table-fan`

where product is my php file.

Current rules:

```
Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ product/$1/$2/$3
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ product.php?uname=$1&pid$2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In .htaccess remove word from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839047/in-htaccess-remove-word-from-url)

Comment: you mean RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ product.php?uname=$1&pid$2 to RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ product.php?uname=$1&pid$2

Comment: Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ product/$1/$2/$3 

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ product.php?uname=$1&pid$2

Answer (score 0):

Try and use this in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ product/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ product/$1
```

This should remove `product` from your URL and leave you with: `http://example.com/Braided/table-fan`.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.