# How to remove a section of url with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've found an [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839047/in-htaccess-remove-word-from-url) by [Fry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276315/fry) which looks to answer my question but I can't get it work.

I have this URL:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/section1/section2/exercise/someurl
```

Which I want to rewrite into:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/section1/section2/someurl
```

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.\*)/exercise/(.\*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

And:

```
RewriteRule ^(.\*)/exercise/(.\*)$ $1/$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

But the URL is not rewritten. I have `RewriteEngine` on and I'm using `RewriteRule` for other rules and they are working correctly.

Here is the [link to the complete .htaccess file](https://pastebin.com/ykPiURx7).

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the regex isn't matching the URL.

You are trying to match an actual asterisk with this `\*`.

What you want is to match everything so the `.` matches the first character. Add `+` and now it's matching everything: `.+`

It's also a good idea to escape the forward slashes like this `\/`

Give this a try: `^(.+)\/exercise\/(.+)$`

Comment: Hi nickstarob, thanks for your suggestions. I followed your hints which are clear  and went with:
^(.+)\/exercise\/(.+)$  $1/$2
but the URL is still not rewritten. This is the [link](https://www.weloveteachingenglish.com/es/lecciones-gratis-para-aprender-ingles/nivel-intermedio/adjetivos-y-adverbios/comparativo-y-superlativo/exercise/86-exercise-1-comparative-and-superlative) that needs to change.

Comment: Is it rewriting at all? Edit your question and include the entire .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi @nickstaroba, thank you for your help. Using your amended regex in combination with RedirectMatch instead of RewriteRule, it works correctly. We are currently using:

RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)\/exercise\/(.+) $1/$2 

I would be interest to know why this works but:

RewriteRule ^(.+)\/exercise\/(.+)$ $1/$2 [NC,R=301,L]

does not. Thanks

Comment: I would need to see the full .htaccess file. RedirectMatch uses [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html). It could be that your Apache installation isn't configured correctly (meaning [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is disabled). Also, does your .htaccess file include the line `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: [Here is the link to the complete .htaccess file.](https://pastebin.com/3DmY6Jf0)

.htaccess includes the line RewriteEngine On

mod_alias is configured on the server

Comment: My guess is that you need to put the redirect down further in the file towards the end after all the other redirects. There’s a lot going on in that `.htaccess` and that could be what’s interfering with the new rule.

Comment: When I have a moment I will try putting the redirect further down the page.